# Is there any manual to explain sfGuard user registration?

Tags: symfony1

I'm looking for a manual. But in the google only links from 2008 year and most of them didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very comprehensive guide which can be found here http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/sfGuardPluginExtraDocumentation